# Get User FingerPrint Details in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, biometrics

I have an android application for which I want to get fingerprints of users using a mobile sensor and verify the details through my API, not local authentication. How can achieve that? From android, I just need the sensor to capture finger details.

Comment: Hi, I have the same case like yours, have you found any solution ?

Comment: No currently its impossible

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: No its not possible

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

```
 var localAuth = LocalAuthentication();
bool didAuthenticate =
    await localAuth.authenticate(
        localizedReason: 'Please authenticate to show account balance');
```

Comment: This is only returning the biometric type I needed the actual fingerprint string.

Comment: That part is fine but as you can see didAuthenticate is returning a boolean value of which I wanted to return the fingerprint data